# XPath select everything until first <br />

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XML:

```
<test>
  <a>
    abc
    <xyz />
    def
    <br />
    ghi jkl
    <br />
    mno pqr
  </a>
  <a>
    xxx
  </a>
</test>
```

In every `<a>` I need to select all subnodes (even textual) until first `<br />`. If there is no `<br />`, I need to select all the subnodes in given `<a>`. So the expected result is:

```
abc
<xyz />
def
```

and

```
xxx
```

I am able to pick "everything before `<br />`" like this:

```
//a/*[following::br]
```

... but it selects everything before the *last* `<br />`. I need to select everything before the *first* one. I tried it like this:

```
//a/*[following::br[1]]
```

... with the same result as before. These also don't select the nodes in "non-`<br />`" `<a>`s.

How can I do this using (prefferably single) XPath expression? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this way (formatted for readability) :

```
//a/node()[
    following-sibling::br[not(preceding-sibling::br)] 
        or 
    not(../br)
]
```

**brief explanation about the predicate expressions (content of `[]`) being used :**

- `following-sibling::br[not(preceding-sibling::br)]` : evaluates to `true` when the corresponding node located before *the first `<br/>`* -expressed as *" `<br>` that doesn't have preceding sibling `<br/>`"*-
- `not(../br)` : evaluates to `true` when the parent `<a>` doesn't have any child `<br/>`

Comment: Seems to work, thank You! Now I am going to study how it works :-)